# Web pages accessible by multiple URLs for SEO reasons

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, seo

I have a bunch of pages with the following structure:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="summary">
        </div>
        <div id="promotions">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I want these pages to be accessible by both:

- /items/one
- /items/two
- /items/three

And:

- /promotional-offers/2014/february/one
- /promotional-offers/2014/february/two
- /promotional-offers/2014/february/three

`/items/...` should just open the page. `/promotional-offers/2014/february/...` should open the page `/items/...` and go to the anchor `#promotions` (scroll down to the appropriate `div`).

- /items/one/#promotions
- /items/two/#promotions
- /items/three/#promotions

I'm not sure though how to set up rewrite rules in `web.config` to help search engines with indexing my pages and avoid having 'duplicate content'.

Comment: Can you clarify for us a little more?

Comment: @KevinBrown Sorry, I don't know how to enhance this question. It seems pretty clear to me as it is. Moreover, I think I've already got the right answer by **marcanuy**. Thank you for your attention anyway.

Comment: looks like this was flagged as lacking information, but your question, to me, seems still valid. If you can rewrite your question to be more easily understood/rephrase, it may help us vote appropriately.

Comment: @KevinBrown I've tried to improve my question. Does it looks better now?

Comment: voted to reopen. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a [Canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) to completely avoid duplicate content, so It won't matter from which page you are showing the same content.

```
<!--url /promotional-offers/2014/february/one-->
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/items/one" />
```